# How to load different .env file in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I need to load a different .env file, named .env.staging under certain conditions.

In .env file

```
APP_NAME="Laravel"
APP_ENV=staging
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=
```

But my .env.staging file is not loaded. How to load different .env

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename .env file in Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286969/how-to-rename-env-file-in-laravel-8)

Answer (score 2):

Test my way: Create `env` folder in root folder with 2 environement files.

Content of `env\.env.staging`:

```
APP_NAME="STAGING MODE"
APP_KEY=base64:AjYSIS9myYGnVkdfaXy2Oz6lY/ofyNhuqN9ZtkKaNm0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Content of  `env\.env.test`

```
APP_NAME="TEST MODE"
APP_KEY=base64:AjYSIS9myYGnVkdfaXy2Oz6lY/ofyNhuqN9ZtkKaNm0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Then set this code to boot file `bootstrap\app.php`:

```
<?php
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
// Load temporary environement variables
$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__, '../.env');
$dotenv->load();
// Get dynamic APP_ENV wrote in .env file
$env = $_ENV['APP_ENV'];
// You can debug by command var_dump to check
// var_dump($env);
switch ($env) {
    case 'staging':
        // Overwrite existing environement variables
        $dotenv = Dotenv::createMutable(__DIR__ .'/../env', '.env.staging');
        $dotenv->load();
        break;
    case 'test':
        // Overwrite existing environement variables
        $dotenv = Dotenv::createMutable(__DIR__ .'/../env', '.env.test');
        $dotenv->load();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Create a route with a view has this title:

```
<title>{{ env('APP_NAME') }}</title>
```

When you change variable APP_ENV in `.env` file:

```
APP_ENV=test
```

You will get the title “TEST MODE”

If you change to:

```
APP_ENV=staging
```

You will get the title “STAGING MODE”

The title changed, mean the environement variables are loaded!

Tested with "laravel/framework": "^8.75" version has built-in package "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4.1".

Answer (score 0):

To use the .env.test file try to restructure your initial bootstrap() method inside of the App/Http/Kernel.php file to look like this:

```
public function bootstrap() 
{
    app()->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.staging');
    parent::bootstrap(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that OP requested L8, but times have changed a bit. Based on the @protoproto answer, a slightly more modern approach tested in L9 and I think should work in L10, using Match from PHP 8.0+:

```php
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

$dotenv = Dotenv::createMutable(dirname(__DIR__), '.env');
$dotenv->load();

if ($_ENV['APP_ENV'] !== 'production') {
    match ($_ENV['APP_ENV']) {
        'staging' => $dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__), 'env/.env-staging'),
        'test' => $dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__), 'env/.env-test'),
        default => $dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__), 'env/.env'),
    };
    $dotenv->load();
}
```

Edited to work only when not in production. No point in doing 2 loads on production when a single complete .env file will be sufficient.